# Using the substitution rule to integrate $ \int_{-1}^{2} (1+4x^2)\,dx $

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I am stuck on an integral problem that came out of an arc length problem.

I have an integral,
$$
\int_{-1}^{2}1+4x^2dx.
$$
When I try to apply the substitution rule, I am left with a variable that I don't know what to do with:
$$
u = 1+4x^2 \rightarrow du =8xdx \rightarrow dx = \frac{1}{8x}du.
$$

My question is as follows:

What do I do with the x in the denominator of dx...or is there a different way to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: If you're going to do that, you will have to write $x$ I terms of $u$. But this is silly. You can integrate the polynomial expression directly, right? Your notation isn't easy to follow, but I think you mean $$\int_{-1}^2(1+4x^2)dx$$ don't you? Isn't this just $$\left.\left(x+\frac43 x^3\right)\right|_{-1}^2 ?$$

Comment: I just edited it as I saw it. I was wondering if the OP was trying to integrate $$\int (1+4x^2)^ndx$$? i.e. n=1/2. Since the question mentions arc length :/.

Comment: $u=1+x^2$ is not a valid substitution for this problem since this function is not one-to-one along the interval of integration.

Comment: See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: Can you give us the original arclength problem.  As Chinny84 points out, most arclength integrals involve a square root.

Comment: Yes. The problem is asking me to find the arc length of \x^2 on the interval {-1<=x<=2}.

Answer (score 2):

If your primary objective is to find the arc length $L$ of the graph of the function $f(x)=x^2$ on the interval $-1\le x\le 2$, then the integral $\int_{-1}^{2}(1+4x^2)\,dx$ which you asked about in your question is not the integral you should be solving.

The correct integral for the arc length is:

> $$L=\int_{a}^{b}\sqrt{1+\left[f^\prime{(x)}\right]^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
> =\int_{-1}^{2}\sqrt{1+(2\,x)^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
> =\color{blue}{\int_{-1}^{2}\sqrt{1+4\,x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x}.$$

Integrals of this type are most straightforwardly solved via trigonometric substitution. After substituting $x=\frac12\tan{(u)}$, the integral for $L$ becomes:

$$L=\frac12\int_{-\tan^{-1}{(2)}}^{\tan^{-1}{(4)}}\sec^3{(u)}\,\mathrm{d}u.$$

This is the famous "secant-cubed" integral. If you haven't encountered this integral before, you can read the "[Integral of secant cubed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_secant_cubed)" Wikipedia page which describes a variety of ways to solve this integral in detail. I leave the computation of the final answer as an exercise.

Answer (score 1):

1) please use MathJax,

2) you don't need substitution here at all: for the integrand $1+4 x^2$ just get two simple integrals.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\int_{-1}^{2}1+4x^2dx = \int_{-1}^2dx + 4\int_{-1}^2x^2dx = x|^{2}_{-1} + \frac{4}{3}x^3|^{2}_{-1} = (2-(-1))+\frac{4}{3}(2^3-(-1)^3) =15
$$